Were Natalie Wood's crossed eyes in The Great Race expected?
Let me set the scene:
The Great Race (1965), Miss Dubois (Natalie Wood) and Max (Peter Falk) are in a cell at the castle of Baron Rolfe Von Stuppe (Ross Martin). They're alone, Professor Fate (Jack Lemon) having been taken. Max is about to escape, though, as Hezekiah Sturdy (Keenan Wynn) sticks his head through the door.
But before that door opens Max raises the bar removed from the window... and it clips Natalie Wood's head. I've looked a number of times and I can't tell that it was scripted and intentional. Natalie might look, just for a moment, a bit surprised at being clipped by the prop, and then she crosses her eyes and slides to the floor. It's hilarious! But it fails continuity (or, at the very least, Blake Edwards takes no advantage of it). Moments later wen we next see Miss Dubois she's kneeling next to Hezekiah (certainly in the script) as if nothing happened and Max slips from the room.
Maybe I'm wrong, but I'd be willing to bet someone lunch that the moment when Max clips Miss Dubois with the raised bar was unscripted and unintentional and Natalie, an excellent actress, did something useful with the moment that director Blake Edwards decided to keep in the film.
So, here's the question. Was that moment in the film when Natalie crosses her eyes and slides to the floor scripted and/or an intentional action in the film? Or did Natalie improvise an unexpected moment? An authoritative answer if we can, please.

